# Alternative to $GLOBALS and Dependency Injection?

Tags: php, standards

One of the projects I'm developing uses third-party libraries. For the moment, I'm storing these objects in a global variable (e.g. `$GLOBALS['_HTMLPurifier']`).

I know everyone says "don't use `$GLOBALS` in object-oriented code, use dependency injection". Problem is, most of these classes are meant to SIMPLIFY for developers. For example:

```
<?php

namespace Sarciszewski\MyProject\Security;

$GLOBALS['_HTMLPurifier'] = new \HTMLPurifier(
    \HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault()
);

class XSS
{
    /* blah */

    public static function clean($input, $context)
    {
        /* logic here */
            $input = $_GLOBALS['_HTMLPurifier']->purify($input);
        /* other things here depending on $context */
    }
}
```

The idea is that anyone using this project literally just needs to do this:

```
<?php
namespace \Otherdev\HelloWorld;
use \Sarciszewski\MyProject as MyP;

$x = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : '';
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"url\" value=\"".MyP\Security\XSS::clean($x, 'attribute')."\" />";
```

I don't want to force people to inject dependencies. I'd rather keep one global instance of these objects. Are singletons appropriate here? Or is there another design pattern that should be followed?

(Worst case scenario: I just say screw it and do it this way because it gets the job done.)

TO CLARIFY: I'm not making a library that other people might use in their framework, I'm making a framework that calls other peoples' libraries.

I want to explicitly hide all dependency-injection except to unit test authors, in a "write less do more" approach. The user should never have to pass an object to anything.

Usability is more important than correctness (which still matters, but not as much). Also, I'd like to minimize additional third-party dependencies. PHPUnit, HTMLPurifier, and Twig are all I really use.

What I'm evaluating:

- Singletons
- Global Variables

What I will not evaluate:

- Dependency Injection

Any fourth options are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what OOP is about.

Most of the time you spend on code doesn't go on writing it. The vast majority of time spent on a codebase is spent on maintaining it, **making it work correctly**. OOP, Tests, Coding style, etc. are all tools to reduce the amount of time you spend maintaining it, to reduce the majority of work you need to do.

OOP is not there to 'simplify' things, on the contrary, OOP is often harder to read and understand than, say functional programming. The point of OOP is to allow easy refactoring of layers, without having to affect the rest of the application.

We can argue about why global variables are bad all day. But at the bottom line, Global space is a great source of bugs. Dependency Injection is a good alternative to that.

For your specific example you, passing the HTML purifying library sounds like a good idea. If tomorrow you'll find a better library that you can use which provides better features or performance, you can relatively easily switch by using Dependency Injection.

Comment: The entire framework is made up of abstraction layers. Behind the scenes, DI makes sense, but I'm alleviating the burden of anyone who uses my framework. I have a "write less, do more" philosophy with this specific specification. I've decided to make a Registry (which is also a Singleton) as a replacement for `$GLOBALS` for exactly one feature; and I've also decided that anyone who dislikes it can simply opt to use another framework since there are no shortage of alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try and homebrew a good DI solution, I would say use a library that's already out there already.

[PHP DI](http://php-di.org/index.html) is really nice as it will allow you to simply type hint any class you want injected into another class in the `__construct` method and it will be automatically included!

This might not seem like an answer, but the question is quite opinion based. Personally I would say using globals is a really bad idea because it's confusing and can introduce some really hard to trace bugs into your code. I would 100% recommend using a very simplistic DI to handle this sort of situation.

In your case (using PHP-DI) you could do the following:

```
class XSS
{
    /**
     * @Inject
     * @var HTMLPurifier
     */
    public static $purifier;

    public static function clean($input, $context)
    {
        /* logic here */
            $input = self::$purifier->purify($input);
        /* other things here depending on $context */
    }
}
```

Comment: I clarified the OP a bit. If I was writing a library, DI would make sense. A framework should, IMO, not require DI.

Comment: I don't really get the clarification sorry. You mention that you want to hide all DI, but I would say $GLOBALS is worse in this case. What if (however unlikely it may be) a library you are using has `global $_HTMLPurifier = false;`? The $GLOBALS array is much more visible than any DI will be. Also, a DI solution with PHP-DI has less setup than your `$GLOBALS` solution in most cases, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: "I would say $GLOBALS is worse in this case." $GLOBALS is hidden from someone who merely uses the framework.
"What if (however unlikely it may be) a library you are using has `global $_HTMLPurifier = false;`?" Then my unit tests will fail with fatal errors and I'll do a git diff to identify the change.

Comment: What I want to do is use something like a singleton, but everyone says they're "a bad practice in PHP".